# Laravel - Sanctum Remove Database Id From Generated Token

Tags: php, laravel, security, laravel-sanctum

Currently I am building rest API using Laravel. For authentication, I am using the Sanctum package. Every time a user is logged in it generate a token that looks like this:

```
"token": "98|b45h97e17VVpugjO71wwURoicIqDQP2ejTkCWwoD"
```

But why Sanctum includes the database id with the token?

[image]

How to remove the database id from the token?

Comment: Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: I would also like to learn how to do this. It doesn't serve my purposes to have the ID prepended to the token, but I don't want to mess up Sanctum's token verification by manually editing it after creation.

Answer (score 4):

I just looked through the source history and found that the ID was introduced in [a well-named commit called `more performant tokens lookup`](https://github.com/laravel/sanctum/commit/5ce9e0539c226fdf3e4e4369996a464521149e97), so that is the reason the ID is part of the token.

But if you look at [the code loading/verifying the token](https://github.com/laravel/sanctum/commit/5ce9e0539c226fdf3e4e4369996a464521149e97) there is a fallback at the beginning in case there is no ID. So you can simply remove it from the token, for example by overriding the `findToken` method.

Answer (score 1):

try this,

Option 1:-

In Controller:-

```
$token = $user->createToken(''project_name')->plainTextToken;
$auth_token = explode('|', $token)[1];
```

Option 2:-

In postman Refer image:-

[image]

Comment: Option 1: how sanctum verify this token? since you modified the original token.

Answer (score 0):

im using laravel 10,

createToken() method in this path :

> vendor\laravel\sanctum\src\HasApiTokens.php

concatenate ID + | + hashToken

you must modify return value of this method :

change this line

> return new NewAccessToken($token, $token->getKey().'|'.$plainTextToken);

with this :

> return new NewAccessToken($token, $plainTextToken);

this should solve the above issue.

actually, i did not directly edit this file
i edited the user model where i was generating the token

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).